# Python array indexing in for loop

Tags: python, arrays

The code I have written works for all values except for when I set xlookfor to 9, which produces an index error. I've messed with changing the index bounds (changing counter to counter = 0) and a few other things, but ended up with the same error. I know this is a simple indexing fix, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
firstlist = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
secondlist = [9, 3, 1, 8, 6, 9, 2]
valuetolookfor = 6

b = 0
e = 0
s = 0
counter = 1

    for i in firstlist: 
        counter += 1
        if i <= valuetolookfor:
            s = i-1
            b = firstlist[counter]
              if b >= valuetolookfor:
                e = i
                break
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Agree on the indents. I think your problem starts with `counter = 1` since Python arrays start with element 0. I think `counter = 0` is where you should start. You are skipping the first element of the array and thus can't find '9' there :)

Comment: Thank you all for you comments. I got it to work via the advice given by Solaxun. I will update the post soon.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to over complicate it with for loops. You can simply the problem:

```
xvals = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
yvals = [9, 3, 1, 8, 6, 9, 2]
xlookfor = 6
yvals[xvals.index(xlookfor)]
>> 8
xlookfor = 9
yvals[xvals.index(xlookfor)]
>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, what you are doing is keeping `b` two steps ahead, at all times, of the current value you are iterating over in `xvals`, or `i` in your case.  I assume what you want to do is keep it one step ahead, so that's problem number one, although not the source of your index error.

The reason for your index error is because once `b` sees 9, `i` is two steps before that, or 7.  You are then trying to access the 7th position in yvals, which is outside of it's bounds of 0-6 (zero based indexing in python).

You are doing this: yvals[7], since e is 7 when the loop finishes.